# The fastest way to write a vector of unsigned long in C++ to a txt file in a loop

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

In my program, I have a huge file where I need to write each line, hash it to get a vector of unsigned long values and write the output vector to a txt file.
What is the fast way to write the vector while optimizing the I/O.

(I/O with binary file are faster, but in my program the size of the output vector is not the same for all lines).

I use the following code:

```
std::ofstream file_out("out.txt");
for(i=0;std::getline(in, comment);i++)
{
   v.clear();
   //hash the line and put values to v
   file_out.open("out.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
   for(j=0;j<v.size();j++)
       file_out<< v[j]<< ",";
   file_out<<"\n";
   file_out.close();
 }
```

Comment: Are you willing to use threads?  (I ask because they're quite a lot more complex than otherwise - but will offer you some potential advantages)

Comment: You can always use system-specific functions to avoid the abstractions added by C++. However, are you certain that this is really a bottleneck? Have you *measured* this? What are your efficiency requirements? How do the code you have not meet those requirements? Are you sure it's not just *premature optimization*?

Comment: If you have different options you can try this http://quick-bench.com/ to bench your options

Comment: ofstream implements buffering, so it's going to be relatively fast, but you need to put your open() call outside the for loop

Comment: @UKMonkey, I can use threads, but how we can access a file in a parallel way ?

Comment: You can define lines in binary too by adding a line-marker (e.g. 0xFFFF) followed by the length.  The marker is for checking purpose, so you can find out when input is bad.

Comment: @Cecile it's not to access the file in a parallel way, but to have one thread reading the file as fast as possible; one to process it; and then one to write the results out.  Disk IO is likely going to end up being your bottleneck and that's you want to read / write as fast as possible

Comment: Not clear what your inputs and outputs are. Do you need to read lines and write a hash of each line?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with any further optimization before following @o_weisman suggestion to open the outputfile only once outside the loop.

Comment: The first line of code opens the output file. The `open` and `close` calls inside the loop are noise, but expensive noise. Open the file **once** and do all the writes.